# Как прижать блоки друг к другу display: inline-block?

Tags: html, css

Как прижать блоки друг к другу, убрать отступы между элементами со свойством  `display: inline-block`?

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyGaVX)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/Отступы-между-элементами-с-inline-block/610041#610041

Answer (score 13):

Дело в том, что inline-block'и - это как слова.
Если между ними в разметке есть пробельные символы, то браузер отобразит пробел.

Перечислю несколько нормальных способов убирания пробелов.
Есть ещё охапка не слишком нормальных - про них промолчу.

## Писать их подряд

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>
</ul>
```

## Или так

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    1
  </li><li>
    2
  </li><li>
    3
  </li>
</ul>
```

## Использовать комментарии

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>1</li><!--
--><li>2</li><!--
--><li>3</li>
</ul>
```

## Не закрывать li явно

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1
  <li>2
  <li>3
</ul>
```

---

## Дополнение

В css нет честного способа не вообще не показывать пробелы между элементами. Есть костыль с `font-size`ом (описанный в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468548/178988)), который не только гробит наследование размера шрифта, но и не работает в некоторых браузерах; есть костыль с `word-spasing`/`letter-spacing`/`margin`, в котором мало того, что под каждый браузер своя конструкция, так он ещё и привязан к шрифту, поскольку ширина пробела различна в разных шрифтах. Убрать пробел из разметки - это честный способ, остальные - нет. А если надо только css, то следует отказаться от `inline-block` и использовать `flex` или `float`, но вопрос не об этом.

А вот [что случается](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137656/) с теми, кто считает иначе.

## На всякий случай приведу вариант с использованием flexbox

Здесь нет привязки к разметке, однако, flex-box в некотором роде подобен таблицам и его не рекомендуется использовать для значительных частей сайта (например, лейаута) из-за возможного снижения производительности.
К тому же стоит проверить поддержку браузерами и необходимость использования префиксов.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: обнулять `font-size` гораздо более нормально, чем уповать на то что программист сохранит такую разметку, при натягивании на движок, например

Comment: @xaja, я уже в соседнем ответе прокомментировал, что в Опере 12 зазор между блоками всё равно есть. Ещё при изменении размера шрифта ты прерываешь наследование и вынужден явно его указать для элементов. Т. е. уже нельзя в одном месте изменить шрифт - надо в двух - подготовим запас граблей заранее. А если программист криворукий и не думает, что в разметке надо сохранять, а что нет, то ничто не поможет.

Comment: Ну да, давайте минусовать правильное решение и городить всякие костыли.

Comment: у вас далеко не полный ответ, с претензией на полный. а регулировать верстку HTML-разметкой такого рода это не костыли?

Comment: @xaja, в css нет честного способа не вообще не показывать пробелы между элементами. Есть костыль с `font-size`ом, который не только гробит наследование, но и не работает в некоторых браузерах; есть костыль с `word-spasing`/`letter-spacing`, в котором мало того, что под каждый браузер своя конструкция, так он ещё и привязан и шрифту, поскольку ширина пробела различна в разных шрифтах. Убрать пробел из разметки - это честный способ, остальные - нет. А если надо только css, то следует отказаться от `inline-block` и использовать `flex` или `float`, но вопрос не об этом.

Comment: ну вот если бы описали такой вариант ответа - то ответ минус бы не получил, потому что он был бы честным и объективным. Сейчас же вы под свою дряхлую оперу 12 все подстраиваете, игнорируя другие варианты

Comment: @xaja, насколько я помню, такое же писалось про китайский вариант хрома и, возможно, сафари. Я не могу точно перечислить список браузеров, где font-size не работает.

Comment: @xaja, дописал это в ответ.

Comment: @xaja, я не игнорирую другие варианты. Честно убрать пробелы через css невозможно, значит надо это сделать через html, а не городить костыли.

Answer (score 4):

Есть много решений, довольно подробно описано здесь http://codepen.io/anon/pen/megQVe, самое простое, изменять font-size ul и li отдельно

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Смотрю из Оперы 12 - не работает.

Comment: А аппаратное решение какое нибудь есть?

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, не используйте _inline-block_ и не надо будет придумывать :-)

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, что знаяит "аппаратное"?

Comment: а как тогда можно все по центру отцентрировать?

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Поменяется font-size или просто сам шрифт, ширина пробела стане другой и конец этой подгонке.

Comment: Даже здесь по-разному выглядит. Опера 12 и Хром в Windows рисуют одинарную границу между элементами, а FF в Linux Mint - двойную.

Comment: Как насчёт варианта с "display: table-cell;" ?

Comment: Да, table-cell возможен, но у него табличные побочные эффекты. Он растягивается по содержимому - overflow использовать затруднительно. Table-cell сам по себе является clearfix'ом. И ещё что-то, на вскидку не вспомню. Если всё это устраивает, то да.

Answer (score 0):

Весь HTML документ представляется узлом документа, в котором каждый HTML тэг является узлом элемента, в котором текст внутри HTML тега является текстовым узлом.

Дело в том, что между тегами располагаются невидимые узлы, содержащие значение /n - символ новой строки в исходном коде.

Чтобы вычислить нужный узел, от которого нужно избавиться, создаёте work.js файл, подключаете его в HTML файл.

В work.js вставляете следующий код:

let nodes = document.body.childNodes      // Получение body и его дочерних узлов
console.log(nodes)                        // Просмотр содержимого переменной nodes

Далее жмёте F12 и во вкладке Console получаете результат. Находите нужные инлайн блоки, и узел между ними. Снова вставляете в ваш work.js следующую строку:

nodes[4].nodeValue = ''       // Изменить значение узла на пустую строку

Так к примеру, если ваши inline-blocks были 3 и 5 по счёту с начала документа, то нужный узел 4. Таким образом мы указываем на конкретный индекс узла [4] переменной nodes.

Чтобы полностью овладеть CSS изучайте JS.