# media queries, max-width

Tags: html, css

[image]

[image]

Внимание, вопрос. Ширина контейнера = 1170px, ширина одного блока wrapper = 291,3px. 1170 > 291,3 * 4, а четвертый блок ни в какую не хочет помещаться рядом с первыми тремя (при wrapper { max-width: 25% }, уменьшать не вариант). Почему так получается?

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 979px) { .wrapper { width: 25%; } }

.container { max-width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: как насчёт отступов?..

Comment: и приложите, пожалуйста, соответствующий данным блокам `css` и отрывок html-кода.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988

Answer (score 0):

А вы учли это расстояние?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое простое решение:

```
wrapper {
    max-width: calc(25% - 5px); /* увеличивайте с 5px до 10px, если все равно вылазит... */
}
```

Comment: можно как-то убрать/изменить расстояние, которые вы отметили? у контейнера и врапера маржины и паддинги 0 стоят

Comment: @urpride код добавьте, я не ванга так-то...

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width : 979px) {
 .wrapper {
  width: 25%;
 }
}

Comment: .container {
 max-width: 75%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

Comment: @urpride [Правьте вопрос, чтобы добавить код по-человечески](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/682992/edit)

Comment: И так всё ясно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988