# Почему перенос строки в коде влияет на отображение?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
      display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>&#8594;</div><div>&#8592;</div>
<hr>
<div>&#8594;</div>
<div>&#8592;</div>
```

Comment: Проблема inline элементов такая ;) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468547/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83 И там еще куча связных вопросов.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот вы туда же человека послали :Р

Comment: @Visman Ну и чего мне с вопросом делать?

Comment: А что вы меня-то спрашиваете? Я не модератор тут :) Можете как дубликат пометить, можете удалить.

Comment: @Visman Вы ответили - значит ответственность на вас. Я плюсик поставил и умываю руки.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/Отступы-между-элементами-с-inline-block/610041#610041