# что такое space bug

Tags: html, css3

что такое space bug ? и какие есть методы его исправления ?

Comment: Этот баг - пробел между инлайн-блоками

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как прижать блоки друг к другу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468547/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот баг - пробел между инлайн-блоками

```css
.ib {
border:1px solid black;
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
```

Для его решения нужно убрать пробелы но код будет выглядеть некрасиво

```css
.ib {
border:1px solid black;
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ib"></div><div class="ib"></div><div class="ib"></div><div class="ib"></div><div class="ib"></div><div class="ib"></div>
```

Или воспользоватся flexbox

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

}
.c {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>


</div>
```

Либо float

```css
.ib {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
<div class="ib"></div>
```

Ну и напоследок отрицательный margin

```css
.ib {
border:1px solid black;
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:inline-block;
margin:-2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
<div class="ib">

</div>
```