# Как убрать отступы между кнопками

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Block</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <!-- Optional theme -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row" style = "margin-left:700px; margin-top:200px;margin:display;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group">
     <button typ ="button" class="btn btn-light"data-toggle="dropdown">Default</button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
        <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class = "divider"></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" class ="btn btn-light"data-toggle="dropdown">Primary</button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
        <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class = "divider"></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Кнопки расходятся из-за невидимого пробела. Надо контейнеру кнопок выставить font-size: 0; а кнопкам уже нужный размер шрифта

Comment: Вы видите здесь контейнер?

Comment: У меня контейнера нет. Я так понимаю в css описать button? Я описал, не помогло.

Comment: Значит контейнер надо создать :) А вообще по идее должно быть достаточно просто убрать все пробельные символы между кнопками в HTML-коде

Comment: Создал контейнер, убрал все пробельные символы. Ничего не поменялось

Comment: Приведите пример и с тем и с другим. Ибо когда я убираю все пробельные символы, то у меня отступ пропадает

Comment: Обновил код, смотри

Comment: Во-первых, пробельные символы между `<div class = "btn-group">` так и не убраны, во-вторых, ещё и паддинг добавился

Comment: Падинг? Где? Пробелы убрал.

Comment: Паддинг — у класса `btn-lg`. Пробелы — нет, не убрали, перед вышеупомянутыми `<div class = "btn-group">` стоят перенос строки и два пробела

Comment: Забыл обновить код. Минуту

Comment: Обновил код. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Потому что вы ничего не изменили: паддинг у класса `btn-lg` так и висит, и перенос строки и два пробела перед `<div class = "btn-group">` по-прежнему имеются. Исправьте эти две вещи, и отступа не будет

Comment: Обновил код. Теперь точно ничего нет. Изменений нет

Comment: Неправда, перенос строки и два пробела вы до сих пор не убрали. Вот выделил на скриншоте красненьким, что вам нужно удалить, раз не понимаете: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfdyn.png

Comment: Сделал. Всё робит благодарю.

Comment: Ну а вообще дубликат вопроса: [Как прижать блоки друг к другу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468547/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83)

Comment: Проверял, Делал, не работает. Здесь нашёл верный ответ.

Comment: Здесь вам помогло абсолютно то же самое, что написано в ответах того вопроса — в частности, убрать пробелы и/или поставить комментарии. Так что дубликат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div.btn-group.btn-lg {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Также не должно быть места пустого между дивами с блоками. поставьте туда комментарии а ля

```
 </div><!-- 
   --><div class="btn-group">
```

Вот весь код на всякий случай:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Block</title>
  <style>
    div.btn-group.btn-lg {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <!-- Optional theme -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row" style = "margin-left:700px; margin-top:200px;margin:display;">
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group btn-lg">
     <button typ ="button" class="btn btn-light"data-toggle="dropdown">Default</button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
        <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class = "divider"></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div><!-- 
   --><div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" class ="btn btn-light"data-toggle="dropdown">Primary</button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
        <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class = "divider"></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```