# Расстояние между блочными элементами

Tags: html, css

Создал 2 блочных элемента одинакового размера, установил свойство display:inline-block, чтобы блоки были ровно напротив друг друга. Когда сохранил изменения и открыл документ в браузере, увидел, что блоки и есть напротив друг друга, но между ними приличное расстояние в 50-60px. Пошел исправлять расстояние между блоками свойством *margin*.

Подскажите, можно ли как-то изменять расстояние между блочными элементами другим способом, кроме *margin*? Просто иногда крайне неудобно исправлять расстояние между блочными элементами только *margin'ом...* Пример приведу внизу, как я исправлял расстояние *margin'ом*, пришлось долго перебирать значения, чтобы добиться оптимального расстояния.

```css
#sitemenu {
  width: 960px;
  height: 540px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 250px auto 250px auto;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

#yticon {
  margin-left: 360px;
}

#kompania {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

#kompania1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

#info {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

#info1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="sitemenu">
  <img id="yticon" src="youtubeicon.PNG" alt="">
  <div id="kompania1">
    <p id="kompania">Компания</p>
  </div>
  <div id="info1">
    <p id="info">Информация</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо добавить комментарий:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div></div><!-- от конца первого к началу второго
--><div style="background: red"></div>
```

Либо писать код в одну строку:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div style="background: red"></div>
```

Comment: Разве отступы между `inline-block` елементами могут быть 50-60px?

Comment: @E_K, с чего Вы это взяли? Думаю, что нет..

Comment: @entithat, я тоже думаю, что нет. Просто автор указывает на отступ 50-60px, так что здесь проблема явно не в пробелах между `inline-block` элементами.

Comment: @entithat, там все нужно поправить)

Comment: @ВасяВасинн, отредактируйте вопрос, постараемся помочь:)

Comment: Нет, не надо) Если не смогу сам сделать так, чтобы блоки были на одном уровне, то отредактирую)

Comment: Здесь трудно сказать.. Верстка такая штука, которую надо видеть и чувствовать)

Comment: Лучше уж задам другой вопрос, там абсолютно иная тема.