# Минимизация html на лету

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с довольно странным явлением:

Есть html страница, на которой присутствуют два `div'a`,

В файле стилей для этих `div'ов` прописано следующее:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
<div>456</div>
```

Демонстрация на `JSFiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/ghaLnj6p/.

То есть, по идее, оба блока должны встать в одну строку и занимать ровно 50%. Но это не так. Получается следующая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`div'ы` стоят на **разных** строчках

Но если в `html` файле поместить эти `div'ы` рядом с друг с другом **без переносов и пробелов**, т.е. вот так (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghaLnj6p/1/):

```
<div>123</div><div>456</div>
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>123</div><div>456</div>
```

то получается следующий результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блоки стали как и положено, занимая 50% ширины.

После этого у меня возник вопрос: **как с этим бороться?** Может стоит применять минимизацию `html` кода на лету, если да, то какой инструмент использовать для этого. Или же существуют какие либо "костыли" для исправления такого поведения блоков. Как вы решаете эту проблему?

Comment: [ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/Отступы-между-элементами-с-inline-block](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/Отступы-между-элементами-с-inline-block)  и [ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468547/Как-прижать-блоки-друг-к-другу-display-inline-block](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468547/Как-прижать-блоки-друг-к-другу-display-inline-block)

Comment: @СергейМишин спасибо. Подскажите еще, есть ли какой либо способ минимизировать html код на лету. Вот например, я открываю файл index.full.html (например), набираю там html код, после чего сохраняю его, и текстовый редактор (ну или, какая либо утилита на linux) при сохранении создает новый МИНИМИЗИРОВАННЫЙ файл index.html . Есть ли что - то подобное?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отступы между элементами с inline-block](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81-inline-block)

Comment: @Alex729 знаю только про сборку и минимизацию js файлов - для этого используют webpack или gulp (в них на самом деле гораааздо больше фич чем просто сборка и минимизация - можно посмотреть туториалы). А про сам html ничего не знаю

Comment: раза 4 в неделю появляется подобный вопрос :), решается через `fontSize:0` у родителя и восстановлением размера у блоков

Answer (score 0):

Это никак не относится к минимизаци, дело в том, что данный "эффект" появляется из-за переноса строки и обычно связан с `inline` элементами.

Я знаю следующие способы "пофиксить" данный "эффект":

**1. Использовать комментарии.**

```
   <div>123</div><!--
--><div>321</div>
```

**2. Float: left;**

```
.parent::after { /* это фикс, чтобы его понять почитайте о свойстве clear */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.parent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

**3. Нулевая высота шрифта у родителя**

```
.parent {
  font-size: 0;
}

.parent > div {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```