# Поменять местами элементы в CSS

Tags: css

Есть список из элементов, первые два занимают по 25% ширины, а каждый третий 50%.
Размещены по три в строке, сколько будет элементов неизвестно, это посты блога которые выводятся циклом вордпресса.

Сложность в том чтобы каждый 6й элемент с его стилями стал на начало строки, поменялся местами с 4м и 5м и так далее

Пробовал применять свойство `order:-1` для каждого 6го элемента - не помогло, так как он улетает в начало списка

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 400px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.child {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 24%;    
    background-color: #CCCCCC;    
    margin: 2px;
}

.child:nth-child(3n) {
  width: 48%; 
}

.child:nth-child(6n) {
  background-color: #fa5a5a;
  order:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[image: картинка[1]]

Comment: `order` пытались использовать?

Comment: конечно, но он отправляет этот элемент в самое начало...

Comment: а как вы это делали? отредактируйте вопрос с вашими попытками использовать `order`

Comment: вот вставил в код для каждого 6го элемента order -1

Comment: вот еще вариант подошел бы задавать width: 48% элементам 3 4 ... 9 10 ... 15 16 ... и тд. возможно вообще такое?

Comment: да, такое возможно

Comment: сдаюсь, выходит только 3 4 выбрать потом 7 ... 10 ...13

Comment: `:nth-child(6n+3)` - каждый 6ой элемент, начиная с 3х (4, 10, 16 по аналогии)

Comment: Жму руку! это на 100% решило мою задачу. буду интенсивнее учить логику с математикой. спасибо

Comment: не за что, желаю успехов!

Comment: оформите как ответ?

Comment: да не, сами выложите решение в ответе, со сниппетом, через 1-2 дня не забудьте поставить галку, это, в будущем, поможет пользователям решить проблему, похожую на Вашу

Comment: @meine, что-то я не пойму, что вы тут в комментариях напридумывали...

Comment: @meine, а, понял. Выделять другие элементы. В принципе логично, но всё-таки в вопросе про другое спрашивалось. Я вот уже два способа придумал, как переставить. Как тебе? С гридом нельзя улучшить?

Answer (score 5):

Flex тут не поможет, но можно воспользоваться более классическими способами:

```css
section {
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(25% - 6px);
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: silver;
}

div:nth-child(6n + 3) {
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  margin-right: 0;
}

div:nth-child(6n) {
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  background-color: #fa5a5a;
  float: left;
}

div:nth-child(6n + 5) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
     <div>1</div><!--
  --><div>2</div><!--
  --><div>3</div><!--
  --><div>4</div><!--
  --><div>5</div><!--
  --><div>6</div><!--
  --><div>7</div><!--
  --><div>8</div><!--
  --><div>9</div><!--
  --><div>10</div><!--
  --><div>11</div><!--
  --><div>12</div><!--
  --><div>13</div><!--
  --><div>14</div><!--
  --><div>15</div><!--
  --><div>16</div><!--
  --><div>17</div><!--
  --><div>18</div><!--
  --><div>19</div><!--
  --><div>20</div><!--
  --><div>21</div><!--
  --><div>22</div><!--
  --><div>23</div><!--
  --><div>24</div><!--
  --><div>25</div><!--
  --><div>26</div><!--
  --><div>27</div><!--
  --><div>28</div><!--
  --><div>29</div><!--
  --><div>30</div>
</section>
```

PS: Комментарии нужны чтобы [избавиться от пробелов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988).

Answer (score 5):

Хм.. Думал, что с `display: grid` получится красивое решение, а получилось какое-то костыльное. Либо я им пользоваться не умею, либо он для такого не предназначен. В любом случае, костыльный велосипед работает:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

div {
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: silver;
}

div:nth-child(3n) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

div:nth-child(6n) {
  background-color: #fa5a5a;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateX(-8px);
}

div:nth-child(6n + 4), div:nth-child(6n + 5) {
  transform: translateX(200%) translateX(16px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
  <div>26</div>
  <div>27</div>
  <div>28</div>
  <div>29</div>
  <div>30</div>
</section>
```

Comment: с `nth-child`, как мне кажется, лучше решение, `grid`'ы для более сложных конструкий) оба ответа ++