# Отступы для ссылок

Tags: html, css

Есть следующий HTML/CSS:

```css
a {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
Some Words...
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
Some Words...
```

Вопрос - как убрать отступы между ссылками и словами `Some Words...`?
т.е. чтобы первая ссылка была прижата к словам `Some Words...` и последняя ссылка тоже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно, можно сделать что то вроде такого:

```css
a {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.words_1 {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: -20px;
}
.words_2 {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="words_1">Some Words...</div>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<div class="words_2">Some Words...</div>
```

Но это весьма грубое и некрасивое решение. Как еще можно выполнить поставленную задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При такой разметке с отступами всё почти хорошо, но остаются пробелы:

```css
a + a {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
Some Words...
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
Some Words...
```

которые [можно убрать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988):

```css
a + a {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
Some Words...<a href="#">Text</a><a href="#">Text</a><a href="#">Text</a><a href="#">Text</a>Some Words...
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a + a {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
Some Words...
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#">Text</a>
Some Words...
```